# PowerShell how to handling prompt for input

Tags: powershell

I have PowerShell that run automatically by window scheduler, most of the time it completed job successfully but sometime it would stuck till window scheduler session timeout. The reason because the PowerShell prompt for input.

I want a solution that can handle this scenario, in case prompt for input then exit the powershell. Can this be done and how?

Note:
Powershell version is >=5

Comment: When does it ask for input?

Comment: sometime, could be due to security warning  or some short of patching that overwrite the OS settings.

Comment: Why is an automatic, scheduled job asking for input? You should post your code and clearly state the problem you are having with it. [Please see how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: powershell prompt for input example : Run only scripts that you trust. While scripts from the internet can be useful, this script can potentially harm your computer. If you trust this script, use the Unblock-File cmdlet to allow the script to run without this warning message. Do you want to run {script name}?


example in this case, I knew what the root cause and can fixed it. How about the other unknown cases ? I want a solution such error handling or what that able to exit powershell immediately if ask prompt for input else powershell will stuck forever till session timeout

Comment: Look for the execution policy and Unblock-File and think about a digital signature with a self-signed certificate to avoid unnessecary prompts at this step. There is no "all fits all" soltion for these cases and its good that it is like this

Comment: I did it and fixed. As I said try to have a solution that can handle unknown case. Thinking to log all the output of powershell to log file by using Start-Transcript command,